# How to pass props in React js?

Tags: reactjs

How to pass props from parent component to child component. I a very new to React just started.

Here is my main component

```
function ApplicationSec() {
  const details = [
    { name: "sam", age: 15 },
    { name: "Kyi", age: 23 },
  ];
  const [userDet, setUserDetails] = useState(details);
  return (
    <>
      <Ban />
      <Listing det={userDet} />
    </>
  );
}
```

Here is my Listing component where I am passing the props from `ApplicationSec` but its working error is `cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')`

```
function Listing({ det }) {
return(  
   <>
    {det.map((items, index) => {
      const { name, age } = items;
      return (
        <>
          <h1>{name}</h1>
          <h2>{age}</h2>
        </>
      );
    })}
  </>;
);
}
```

One more question is it possible to pass the `setUserDetails` function to `Ban` component and do some manipulation like add more object to into userDet like so

Comment: It looks like this code has been edited in a way that makes the original issue no longer reproducible. Here's a Code Sandbox with the working implementation. https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-vaughan-eqr70

Comment: When i try in my local it says det is undefined and the first name and last name doesn't load

Comment: Thanks for that info. Check out the Code Sandbox... how does it differ from your code?

Comment: I am not using exactly the same but the concept is almost same I am just using routes also

Comment: In order to help, we'll need to see all of the code necessary to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You're not returning anything from the Listing component. First try returning the fragment.

```js
function Listing({det}) {
  return (
    <>
      {
        det.map((items,index) => {
          const {name , age} = items;
          return(
            <h1>{name}</h1>
            <h2>{age}</h2>
          )
        })
      }
    </>
  );
}
```

If that doesn't work console logging what `det` is in the Listing component. It should be getting that value just fine based on your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the return statement in your second snippet

Regarding your second question, yes you can

```js
const setUserDetails = (user) => {
setUserDetails(user)}
```

```
<Ban setDetails= {setUserDetails} />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

In the main component

```
import { useState } from "react";
import Listing from "./Listing";

export default function App() {
  const details = [
    { name: "sam", age: 15 },
    { name: "Kyi", age: 23 }
  ];
  const [userDet, setUserDetails] = useState(details);
  const [formState, setFormData] = useState({ name: "", age: "" });
  return (
    <>
      <label>Name: </label>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={formState.name}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setFormData((prevState) => {
            return { ...prevState, name: e.target.value };
          });
        }}
      />
      <label>Age: </label>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={formState.age}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setFormData((prevState) => {
            return { ...prevState, age: e.target.value };
          });
        }}
      />
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setUserDetails((prevState) => {
            return prevState.concat({
              name: formState.name,
              age: formState.age
            });
          });
        }}
      >
        Add
      </button>
      <Listing det={userDet} />
    </>
  );
}
```

And your `Listing` component

```
import React from "react";

const Listing = ({ det }) => {
  return (
    <>
      {det &&
        det.map((items, index) => {
          const { name, age } = items;
          return (
            <>
              <h1>{name}</h1>
              <h2>{age}</h2>
            </>
          );
        })}
    </>
  );
};

export default Listing;
```

Code sandbox => https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-edison-nn7dd?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @SingUser, check this out!!

Comment: I tried this but I didn't get any error but the name and age is not displayed when I debug ```det``` is undefind its undefined